# IEnumerable.Contains() keeps querying data source instead of memory

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code to try and find a new unique value between 1000-10000 that I can assign to a userId.  I do this by querying the DB for all userIds and finding the first non-used one:

```
    var users = userDbContext.Data.Select(a => a.UserId);

    for (int i = 1000; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (!users.Contains(i))
        {
            this.Id = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

For some reason, every iteration of this loop is querying the database table instead of just querying what's in memory.  Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Remember, a query is a *question*, not an *answer*. You said "ask the database this question nine thousand times", and that's what you got.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hover the pointer over the `var` keyword and you'll see it's still an `IQueryable<int>`.

You should turn this into a collection to process it in-memory, like so:

```
var users = userDbContext.Data.Select(a => a.UserId).ToList();
```

`.ToList()` will enumerate over the queryable, which will execute it.

But you can do better: since you're mostly using `Contains`, use a `HashSet` where it's a *O(1)* operation:

```
var users = new HashSet<int>(userDbContext.Data.Select(a => a.UserId));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you call ToList() or something similar to execute the query the data will be in memory.

The linq query isnt actually executed until it is needed.